# How far does the connection between the boundary and the derivative go?

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations

The generalized Stokes theorem $$\int_M d\omega=\int_{\partial M} \omega$$ for a compactly supported differential form $\omega$ on a compact manifold with boundry $M$ establishes a sort of duality between the $d$ operator and the $\partial$ operator. I was wondering how far that connection might go in respect to differential equations.

For example, we know that $$df=fdt$$ together with $f(0)=1$ results in arguably one of the most important functions in math, the exponential. Might one pursue an equation of the type $$\partial X=X$$ in an analogous manner, solving for $X$?

Now, this correspondence doesn't seem to make it very far. If we look at the real numbers with the euclidean topology, there are a lot of solutions to this equation while to the analogous differential equation there is only one solution. But maybe with further restrictions one could formulate a sort of theorem of uniqueness and or existence.

Has work been done on anything that might look like this?

Comment: If you stick with manifolds with boundary, of course there is no finite-dimensional solution. I cannot think of any infinite-dimensional interpretation. Remember that set boundary and manifold boundary are very different.

Comment: @TedShifrin The equation $\partial X=X$ (manifold boundary) has exactly one solution. :)

Comment: Indeed @MoisheKohan. I always forget the d*** empty set.